# Create new table from old table and add 2 new columns

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is working fine, it creates one MySQL table from another based on selected fields.

My problem is I also want 2 new empty columns in the new table.

How do I create a new table based on an existing table, but with added empty columns?

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"CREATE TABLE matchstats SELECT hometeam, fthg, awayteam, ftag FROM results");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to create table failed");
}
```

Comment: look for alter Table

Comment: @reporter yes - thankyou - I am aware of alter table I just wondered if I can do it all in 1 query - but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  new_column1 DECIMAL(5,2),
  new_column2 DECIMAL(5,2)
) SELECT * FROM table1 ;
```

[see demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddeb8d)

Comment: Awesome - perfect - I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 0):

First You can create new table from existing table. Below query is for that

```
create table `matchstats` AS Select * from `results`
```

Then you can add whatever columns you want into new table. Below query for that

```
ALTER TABLE `matchstats`
ADD DateOfBirth  date
```

Comment: yeah - create is working fine - it is just those 2 new columns - seems separate alter table is only way - thanks